# New features from Lotus Notes 7 to 8.5

Tags: upgrade, lotus-notes

Next month `Lotus Notes`, my corporate email client, will be upgraded from version 7 to 8.5.

Which are the new features should I expect?

Comment: Note that each of the "new features" is to activate or not, from your sysadmin (like the IM in previous version), so there is a difference between what is new in this version, and what you will actually get :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These [official slides](http://www.slideshare.net/edbrill/lotus-notes-85-version-to-version-comparison) are giving you the comparison between Lotus versions (sorry, I haven't found them as a simple list).

Comment: Thank you for the slides, very clear. Multilevel undo, instant spell check for productivity seems the most useful additions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new splash screen and it is slower to load - this means you have lots of time to admire the new splash screen.